# recycler view перенос объектов drag-and-drop

Tags: android, recyclerview, drag-n-drop

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста,  никак не могу найти хоть какую-либо полезную информацию для решения следующей задачи:
[image: example]

требуется подобный интерфейс, т.е. переноса элемента с одного recycler в другой с отрисовкой. Ознакамливался с такой статьей по drag-and-drop:
[drag-and-drop](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.bqad1zxr7) 
но не очень понимаю как из подобного можно реализовать то что выше.
Буду рад любой подсказке, намеку и прочему.

Comment: почитайте тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055292/android-drag-and-drop-imageview-ontouchlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется вам нужно использовать библиотеку Advanced RecyclerView для данной задачи

импортируете в gradle так:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.10.2@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Более подробную информацию о данной библиотеке можете получить [тут](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview#advanced-recyclerview)